# How to get input from command line using mongo javascript?

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb script use **print()** do output. Is there a method to get the input?

Comment: Just adjust your shell command to reflect your input values.

Comment: normally you wouldn't be using the shell for interactive session with an end user - can you describe exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky i am writing a script file to init my mongodb. eg. user can decide weather to recreat a db if it exists. and for more the script can let some people who not familiar with mongo to do some basic shell command:)

Comment: are you writing your script in js? shell script? something else?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky yes, i'm writing my js file.